# Is this method of ajax login secure at all?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, security, password-storage

I am building a login form using ajax php and MySql.

I've done my fair share of research and I didn't like much posts found online, so I've built the below code.

My question is, is this secure at all? I'm not using any hashing and I'm not sure how it would be done with ajax. All the examples are much appreciated

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form[name=loginForm]').submit(function() {

        $.post('ajax.php', {    username: $('[name=username]').val(), 
                                password: $('[name=password]').val()},
        function(data){
            if(data.success){

                alert('welcome');

            }else{  
                alert("incorrect"); 
            }
        }, 'json'); 

        return false;   
    });
});
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST){

     /** Fetch data from mysql **/
        $u = $_POST['username'];
        $p = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE  username='$u' AND password='$p' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $_SESSION['userid'] = $row["username"];
                    $_SESSION['userid'] = $row["username"];

                    $data['success'] = true;
                } 
            } 
            else 
            {

                $data['success'] = false;

            }
     /** Fetch data from mysql **/

    echo json_encode($data);
}  ?>
```

THANKS ALOT

Comment: Answer. Do not go live with this. Also why do you have a while loop??  It's just one record

Comment: There are guidelines on how to handle passwords. Check NIST. In short, no this is not secure.

Comment: [OWASP: PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet), [OWASP: SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) ([xkcd: Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/))

Comment: @Akintunde thanks for the heads up :) I had trouble fetching the record without the while loop :S

Comment: Thansk guys. I have not found any decent once that are easy to understand

Comment: @Andreas I've read all three links, the last one is funny lol. So if I add the following, does that mean i am protected? >> $u = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
  $p = md5($_POST['password']);

Comment: I dont know why i was down voted and ignored when I all I asked for was some help...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that you read and **understood** the two OWASP links. That's some really heavy stuff which is discussed there. And for your question I will quote OWASP: _"This technique should only be used as a last resort, when none of the above are feasible."_

Comment: So are you advising me not to use open web application security project? is OWASP my last resort? @Andreas

Comment: I've seen many websites use it and its increasingly popular for its ux capabilities. It be ideal if I can use it securely

Comment: Don't worry about downvotes. They happen. They often happen when a question shows some code that's notoriously dangerous, like `WHERE password = "'$password"'` We're not supposed to downvote questions unless they show signs of poor research, but people do anyway. Don't sweat it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, is this secure at all?

No, it is not secure.

> I'm not using any hashing and I'm not sure how it would be done with ajax.

Authentication actually cannot be done with ajax. With respect, you're barking up the wrong tree.

Start by reading this part of the PHP manual. http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php  Go read it now. We'll wait.

Welcome back. You should *never* put your plain text password into a database. If you're not sure why that's true read about the "Ashley Madison data breach" online or go visit https://haveIBeenPwned.com/

You want to make it as hard as possible for a cybercriminal who steals your user table to guess your users' passwords. If you store them as text, they are trivial to guess.

Let's say your users are registered already. The point of your password authentication is to

1. gather the username and password from the user.
2. look up the user by name in your database, pulling back the hashed password.
3. compare the hashed password in your database with the one you gathered from the user. [php's `password_verify()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) does this well.
4. if the validation fails, refuse the user's information. **Do not** give them any hint what was wrong. Simply tell them "your login failed." You don't want to tell them "you gave the right username but the wrong password."
5. if the validation succeeds, you then generate a session for that user so they can continue to use other pages in your web app without logging in again. [Read about php sessions here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.session.security.management.php).
6. you use a session id to represent the session. A session id is a hard-to-guess data token with a limited lifetime. php offers a [`session_create_id()` method for this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-create-id.php).
7. you put that session id in a cookie and feed it back to your browser.  **You can't reliably feed cookies to browsers with AJAX** so your authentication strategy won't work.
8. Subsequent requests to your web app present the session id in the cookie. You check it to make sure it it's valid and it hasn't timed out. Then you do what the user asks you to do.

Comment: Lament: in these days of Equifax hacks why do beginners try to do their own authentication code? The intertoobz are crawling with cybercreeps. They're smarter and better motivated than the rest of us.

Comment: Thanks alot for this wonderful and insightful answer. I did not know I was doing my own authentication code, until now. Thanks very much!